# How to find the degree of an extension field?

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

> How to find the degree of an extension field ?

Let $f:=T^3-T^2+2T+8\in\mathbb Z[T]$ and $\alpha$ be the real root of $f$. Why is then $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ is a number field of degree $3$ ?

I've seen somewhere that $[\mathbb Q(r):\mathbb Q]\le n$ if $r$ is a root of an irreducible polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb Q$ of degree $n$. What does it change in my case, if the extension field would contain also the other roots, they're also roots of the polynomial $f$, how does the degree increase ?

Obviously, by finding an element in $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$, which is not in $\mathbb Q$, the degree cannot be $1$, so it remains to show that, it is also not $2$. Or is there a better way, can we find $3$ field embeddings ?

Comment: If the polynomial is irreducible, then that's true. It is irreducible, because it has no rational roots and has degree $3$.

Comment: Actually, if $r$  is a root of an _irreducible_ rational polynomial of degree $n$, then the degree $[\Bbb Q(r):\Bbb Q]$ is guaranteed to be _equal_ to$~n$. Simply because $r^0=1,r,\ldots,r^{n-1}$ are linearly independent over$~\Bbb Q$ from the hypothesis ($r$ cannot be root of another monic irreducible polynomial as well, since that would make the$~\gcd$ of those distinct irreducibles distinct from$~1$, which is absurd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Fact**: Consider two polynomials $f$ and $p$ over $\Bbb{Q}$, with $p$ irreducible. It can be proved that if $f$ and $p$ share a root, then $p$ divides $f$.

How does this help? Suppose that $\alpha$ is a root of an irreducible polynomial $f \in \Bbb{Q}[X]$ of degree $n$ and that $[\Bbb{Q}(\alpha):\Bbb{Q}] = m < n$. Since $[\Bbb{Q}(\alpha):\Bbb{Q}]$ is the dimension of $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ as a *vector space*, this means that there are $q_0,\dotsc,q_{m-1} \in \Bbb{Q}$ such that
$$
\alpha^m = q_0 + q_1 \alpha + \dotsb + q_{m-1} \alpha^{m-1}
$$
hence $\alpha$ is a root of $g(X) = X^m - q_{m-1} X^{m-1} - \dotsb - q_0$. By the aforementioned fact it follows that $g$ divides $f$ in $\Bbb{Q}(X)$, but this is absurd because $f$ is irreducible.

---

As for what happens when adjoining other roots, that depends on how much your field differs from being Galois.

For example, consider $f(X) = X^3 - d$, with $d$ a cube-free integer. Then its roots are $\sqrt[3]{d},\zeta_3\sqrt[3]{d},\zeta_3\sqrt[3]{d}$, where $\zeta_3$ is a primitive root of unity, i.e. a root of $X^2 + X + 1$. Then $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha_1, \alpha_2) = \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{d},\zeta_3)$ has degree $6$ for any two distinct roots $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ of $f$.

On the other hand, say, adding any root of $X^4 + X^3 + X^2 + X + 1$ to $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$ won't change the degree of the extension (which is $5$).

---

**Regarding your specific problem**: The splitting field of an irreducible cubic polynomial $f$ with rational coefficients can have either degree $3$ or degree $6$. In particular if, like in your case, $f$ has only one real root, then its splitting field has degree $6$. For example, you can find the full treatment of this at [PlanetMath](http://planetmath.org/galoisgroupofacubicpolynomial), where there is a proof that the splitting field of $f$ is
$$
\Bbb{Q}(\alpha, \sqrt{D})
$$
where $\alpha$ and $D$ are, respectively, a root and the discriminant of $f$.

*Note*: $f$ has one real and two complex roots [iff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Cubic) its discriminant is negative, thus in this case it is always true that $\sqrt{D} \notin \Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: So you say that if the polynomial is irreducible then the degreeof the extension is the degree of the minimal polynomial, and by a theorem I know that if the polynomial is of degree $2$ or $3$ it is reducible iff it has a zero in $\mathbb Q$, this is enough. OK but what does it change if we adjoin also the other roots ?

Comment: Your example behaves just like $X^3 - d$, only with harder [computations](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=roots%20of%20x%5E3%20%2D%20x%5E2%20%2B%202%20x%20%2B%208).

Comment: You mean to show without wolframalpha that the real root is not rational ?

Comment: No, all the roots cannot be rational if your polynomial is irreducible (which is easy to prove, as others pointed out). WA was just a quick way to show you that your polynomial has three roots, one real and two complex.

Answer (score 3):

The polynomial is irreducible over the rationals, because its possible rational roots are to be found among $\pm1$, $\pm2$, $\pm4$ and $\pm8$. A direct check shows these numbers are not roots.

Since the polynomial has degree $3$, reducibility over $\mathbb{Q}$ coincides with having a rational root.

So, if $\alpha$ is a root of the polynomial, $f$ is its minimum polynomial and it's a standard result that the degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ equals the degree of the minimum polynomial.